# settimeout using a variable input

Tags: javascript, html, variables, settimeout, timedelay

I want to create a setTimeout with the timeout amount being input by the user.

e.g. I want the user to be able to delay the playback of an audio sample by manually inputting the delay time into a box.

Is it possible to trigger setTimeout from variable input or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Yes, certainly possible. What have you tried / is not working?

Comment: I've not tried anything so far. I've been trying to find out how to go about doing this with no success.

Comment: <button onclick="playVid() + countup() + setTimeout(playAudio4, 1000) + setTimeout(playAudio2,11000) + 
        setTimeout(playAudio1, 19000) +
        setTimeout(playAudio3, 31000) + 
        setTimeout(playAudio2, 39000) + hideButton()" type="button">Play</button>

my code so far. which works although it's probably a very messy way of doing this. I want to create a button which triggers a video playback along with audio sample playbacks that are delayed. 

Instead of the set in stone timeouts, I wish to change it so the end user can set the timeouts.

Comment: please [edit] the question instead of putting code into comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by collecting the number and using it as the timeout variable.

```html
<input type="number" id="timeout">
```

Then you can collect it with `.value`

```js
var timeout = +document.querySelector("#timeout").value;
setTimeout(my_function(), timeout);
```

Remember this is the number of milliseconds, so to make it into seconds multiply `timeout` by `1000`.

```js
var timeout = +document.querySelector("#timeout").value;
// convert from milliseconds to seconds
setTimeout(my_function(), timeout * 1000);
```

Here is a complete example with seconds.

```js
function timeout() {
    var milliseconds = +document.querySelector("#timeout").value;
    var seconds = milliseconds*1000;
    setTimeout(() => {
        alert("Timeout has ended");
    }, seconds);
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="timeout" value="1">
<button onclick="timeout()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const delay = parseInt(window.prompt("number in millisecond"));

  setTimeout(() => {
    window.alert("Its took me " + delay + " millisecond to show up");
  }, delay);
```

I wish this is what are you looking for

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Demo Code.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
   <input type="number" name="delayTime"/>
   <button>Submit Time Delay</button>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit",(e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  
  setTimeout(()=>{
    document.querySelector(".audio").play()
 },parseInt(`${form["delayTime"]000`}));
  
});
```

**NOTE:** You will need to give time as seconds, I have simply added 3 zeros to make it seconds.

Answer (score 0):

By using an `<input>` element you can have the user set a value for a delay. Then when you want to call the `setTimeout`, use the value of that input as the delay.

```js
const fire = document.getElementById('fire');
const delay = document.getElementById('delay');

fire.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const duration = Number(delay.value);

  setTimeout(() => {
    alert(`hello after ${duration}ms`);
  }, duration);
});
```

```html
<label for="delay">Set the delay</label>
<input type="number" id="delay" value="500">
<button type="button" id="fire">Fire</button>
```